# Indian National, Living in New Zealand looking to go to Europe

Tags: visas

My wife's nationality is Indian, We currently both reside in New Zealand.
My wife holds a New Zealand permanent residence and we are looking at getting a Shengen Visa, however, being 1) in New Zealand Time Frame and 2) Europe's time is night time for us makes it hard for us to get this sorted quickly.

My wife has just received her British Holiday Visa - Approved Today!

We are looking to attend Europe from June 1st through to 6th July 2018.

Our current timeframe appears below:

- Leave New Zealand:
- UK   3rd-7th 5 days Total
- France   8th-11th 3 days Total
- France   11th-13th 3 days Total
- Portugal 14th-17th   4 days Total
- Spain 18th-20th  3 days Total
- Croatia  21st-26th 5 days Total
- UK 27th-29th 3 days Total
- Belgium 30th-3rd 4 days Total
- Then Back to New Zealand

My wife has attempted to book an appointment via the French Embassy, however, they currently only have 1 appointment available on the 31st May and we fly out of the country that day.

We have just found a number for the Belgium Consulate in Wellington, NZ so we will be contacting them early tomorrow morning NZTime.

We also have mixed reviews as to if Croatia is currently part of the shengen accepted countries - any clarification on this would be very much appreciated.

Just seeking any and all advice to help my wife get a visa so we can finally enjoy our trip.

To Note; I am British so visas (Luckily for me) won't be a problem.

Comment: ... postpone your vacation to next year and start planning in better time then?

Comment: That’s a huge amount of travelling, you’ll be spending half your time travelling to/from or in airports on top of adjusting to jet lag!  Croatia is not currently in Schengen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area

Comment: I am not so sure where you see any complexity in this situation. As a wife of an EU citizen, she has the right to get a visa to travel together with you and it is a straight forward process, where barely any documentation is needed. You do however have to get an appointment at the competent consulate and you simply have to plan a bit in advance. There is no realistic way for you or your wife to get through the application process and get an approved visa in just three weeks.

Comment: Tor makes an excellent point, but note that (as you are a UK citizen) the right of an expedited visa for travel with an immediate family member who's an EU citizen does *not* extend to your visit to the UK.

Comment: Also, as the U.K. is your first destination your wife should apply for that visa first, which will further strengthen her Schengen application (if needed) but also delay it because she won’t be able to submit it until she has her passport back. You can’t do them simultaneously. Realistically you probably need at least 2 months.

Comment: @Traveler for the wife of an EU citizen there is no need to strengthen the application. It can only be refused if she is a threat to public safety, public health, or public policy. There's no need to overcome presumption of immigrant intent, nor to demonstrate financial means, nor any of the other usual visa application hurdles.

Comment: Luke, you've listed France twice consecutively. Is that correct?  Also, in seeking appointments, have you noted that your wife is to travel under the free movement directive? Such visas are not only free of charge but should also be issued expeditiously; that requirement may help you here.

Comment: My proposal to the OP is to reduce the itinerary to 4 countries, preferably visiting them in one rough geographical direction. Cut out the UK since you will never get a visa for your wife in time and pray to get a Schengen visa within in the next three weeks. Don't book any hotels until the Schengen visa has been approved - but you are running into main summer season which will reduce the amount of available hotels by a lot. In short: You should travel next year.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thank you for commenting - Unfortunately postponing isn't an option I have a sick family member we wish to see while we are in England.

Comment: @Traveller Thank you for commenting - Yes this, funnily enough, was my argument but the wife gets, what the wife wants :)
Asi i have just mentioned below to user-Madhatter, my wife just received her Approved UK Holiday Visa, so that's getting there and coming back out of the way.

Comment: @MadHatter - Thanks for commenting - noted, My wife has just received her UK Approved Holiday Visa, so we got that going for us right now...

Comment: @Phoog - Thanks for commenting - twice in France is correct, We are visiting both Paris and Bordeaux, The trouble we are finding is who do we tell, we are trying to call the Belgium consulate today during NZ business hours, however, we only got through to voicemail, will try again but as I mentioned, not sure who we should be approaching the visa from and where to get the free & expedited visa from - Thank you very much!

Comment: @Sebastian - Thank you for commenting - Thank you for the advice, we have already booked all Flights / Trains  & Accommodation except Croatia.

Comment: How are you traveling from UK to France?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments/questions.  Putting on hold for now.